# How to rename React components _and_ have the 'imports' refactored too?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, refactoring

When renaming a React component, how do you ensure the new name is used everywhere?

E.g. `OldComponent` -> `NewComponent`

The IDE I'm currently using (IntelliJ IDEA) only part does the job. For example, it will leave the variables with the old name in `import` statements:

```
import OldComponent from 'components/NewComponent.jsx'
...
<OldComponent />
```

Do people generally avoid refactoring in JS, or are there solutions/tools that can do this? (Or do people just kinda get used to manually refactoring? :D)

Comment: I usually do a case-sensitive replace in all files for lower and upper case. Does job 95% of time.

Comment: Thanks @MartinMazzaDawson - one of my components is called `Main`, which I believe comes under the 5% of components this doesn't work so well for (at least in my codebase where `Main` is used in several places).

Comment: Yes, this is a problem :)

Comment: I'd probably do a global find-replace and the use `git add -p` to only add the ones you want to change.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For me personally, the solution was to use TypeScript.

IntelliJ will automatically update the imports for you (if you use TypeScript).

Answer (score -1):

I think that <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> should do the job. It does the renaming for all matching cases. You could also find this in *context menu -> Refactor -> Rename...*